# How to edit nibbles inside a variable?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following code.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    size_t value = stoul(argv[1], 0, 16);   
    size_t nibble = stoul(argv[2]);         
    size_t replacement = stoul(argv[3]) % 16;   

    cout << hex << value << '\n';       
}
```

I want to write supplementary to this code such that I can type `./a.out value nibble replacement` in my terminal, and it will replace whatever digit is in the specified nibble by the replacement. So for example, I would want to type `./a.out 22334 3 11` so that the output I get is `2b334`. Nibble here indicates the nibble offset. How would I make my program access the specified nibble?

Comment: Bitwise shifts will help you here

Comment: Why does code use `size_t` rather than `unsigned long` to match the return type of `stoul()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
value &= ~( 0xF << ( nibble * 4 ) );
value |= replacement << ( nibble * 4 );
```

---

First we create a mask.

```
                                           1 1 1 1   0xF

             1 1 1 1   0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0   0xF << ( nibble * 4 )

   1 1 1 1   0 0 0 0   1 1 1 1   1 1 1 1   1 1 1 1   ~( 0xF << ( nibble * 4 ) )
```

We use this to clear bits from the original value.

```
   0 0 1 0   0 0 1 0   0 0 1 1   0 0 1 1   0 1 0 0   value

&  1 1 1 1   0 0 0 0   1 1 1 1   1 1 1 1   1 1 1 1   mask
   -----------------------------------------------
   0 0 1 0   0 0 0 0   0 0 1 1   0 0 1 1   0 1 0 0   value & mask
```

Then we prepare the value to insert.

```
                                           1 0 1 1   replacement

             1 0 1 1   0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0   replacement << ( nibble * 4 )
```

Then merge it in.

```
   0 0 1 0   0 0 0 0   0 0 1 1   0 0 1 1   0 1 0 0   value & mask

             1 0 1 1   0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0   replacement << ( nibble * 4 )
|  -----------------------------------------------
   0 0 1 0   1 0 1 1   0 0 1 1   0 0 1 1   0 1 0 0
```

Comment: In creating the mask, why does the '~' operator create an extra 1111 in front of the mask in the second step? I know that it turns 1's into 0's and in reverse, but why does it give you an extra 1111 in front?

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to C++ in general. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the output stream class to work with a string. This makes it much easier to replace any position.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::ostringstream outstream_value;
  outstream_value << std::hex << std::stoul(argv[1], 0, 16);
  std::string hexstr = outstream_value.str();
  const std::size_t length = hexstr.length();

  std::ostringstream outstream_replace;
  outstream_replace << std::hex << std::stoul(argv[3]) % 16;
  const char replace_char = outstream_replace.str()[0];

  const std::size_t nibble = std::stoul(argv[2]);

  if ( length >= nibble + 1 )
    hexstr[length - nibble - 1] = replace_char;

  std::cout << hexstr;
  return 0;
}
```